# Is Mono capable of hosting ASP.NET MVC WebAPI in mod_mono yet?

Tags: apache, mono, apache2, asp.net-web-api

Pretty much as the title says - I've tried to get this going as per:

http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2011/12/get-started-with-amazon-ec2-run-your-net-mvc3-razor-site-in-the-cloud-with-linux-mono-2/

And whilst I can get a very simple ASP MVC 4 site going - anything with a WebAPI project involved gives me 500s and very cryptic errors in my apache logs:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.GetCustomEncoderFromConfig () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder].InitValue () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I'm guessing not but want to know if I'm doing something basic wrong!

Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Mono 3.0.2, ASP.NET WebAPI is not yet supported. WebAPI uses [HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406798.aspx) to get the HTTP request data, but this is not yet implemented in Mono. If you get past the errors mentioned  above (which may be due to incorrect configuration in Web.config), you will encounter an error similar to this error:

Missing method System.Web.HttpRequest::GetBufferlessInputStream() in assembly /opt/mono-3.0.0/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll, referenced in assembly /tmp/www-data-temp-aspnet-0/2956977a/assembly/shadow/5cf10065/cf4140da_93b040bf_00000001/System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll

See https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8008 for the bug report.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - do you know if that is the ONLY blocker to making WebAPI work or just the first in a long road of changes required to the Mono runtime?

Comment: @KieranBenton I'm not 100% sure - `GetBufferlessInputStream` not being implemented was the first major roadblock I ran into and I wasn't sure of the best way to work around it. At the moment it might be worth using ServiceStack instead, as it's designed to run on Mono and has great community support.

Comment: HttpRequest.GetbufferlessInputStream() is now apparently fixed with [this pull request](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/561#issuecomment-13977848).

Comment: Lot of things has changed, for one that bug is fixed. Ballmer was removed, Web API/MVC was opensourced. Is it working already?

Comment: @Ciantic WebAPI was already open source when this was posted :). Not sure if it works now, I haven't tried it since posting this answer. MVC 4 definitely works but there's a few quirks with MVC 5 since Mono doesn't have an implementation of the async ASP.NET stack.

Answer (score 2):

> ServiceStack is no longer open source

You can take a look at [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/).  Its a well supported alternative to WebApi and it also runs on Mono.  Its very fast, extensible, and powerful; its documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki) and [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack).

Comment: Thanks Donny, I'm aware of that... this post was made while it was still opensource.